# How to convert json to Python List?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pycurl

I want to get data in form of list while using pycurl but it's showing an object of json :( 
Could you please tell me simplest way how to break and get list out of it?
Thanks in advance for guiding :)
Here is my code:

```
import pycurl 
import json  
from io import BytesIO 

c = pycurl.Curl()
data = BytesIO()

c.setopt(c.URL,'https://api.angel.co/1/jobs')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, data.write) 
c.perform()
fetched_data= data.getvalue()
print (fetched_data);
```

Answer (score 3):

Decode the json with the `json` module you already imported:

```
result = json.loads(fetched_data.decode('utf8'))
```

I hardcoded the encoding here; the JSON RFC states UTF-8 is the default, but you could see if the `Content-Type` response header has a `charset` parameter that tells you the actual encoding.

I'd not use `pycurl`; it is *really, really cumbersome* to deal with. Use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) instead, it can handle JSON for you, out of the box. It handles decoding of the bytestream to Unicode *for you*:

```
import requests

result = requests.get('https://api.angel.co/1/jobs').json()
```

That specific URL returns a JSON *object*, resulting in a Python dictionary:

```
{'jobs': [{'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/jobs?startup_id=267120',
            'created_at': '2014-02-06T08:07:35Z',
            'equity_cliff': '0.0',
            'equity_max': '0.0',
            'equity_min': '0.0',
            'equity_vest': '0.0',
            'id': 22672,
            'salary_max': 0,
            'salary_min': 0,
            'startup': {'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/nationsroot-1',
                         'community_profile': False,
                         'company_url': 'http://nationsroot.com',
                         'created_at': '2013-09-20T07:55:25Z',
                         'follower_count': 5,
                         'hidden': False,
                         'high_concept': 'Bridge between citizens and politicians',
                         'id': 267120,
                         'logo_url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/267120-9513670dbfe74c170201df0e385d1c2c-medium_jpg.jpg?buster=1379663721',
                         'name': 'NationsRoot',
                         'product_desc': 'NationsRoot helps you find profiles and report cards of politicians, share your thoughts and rate your political leaders. We believe that citizens are not absolved of their duties once they are done voting. So, We provide a platform where you can rate the quality of government provided services to create real time Report Cards for all politicians.\r\n\r\nOn the other hand, Politicians will have the detail analytics about requirements of citizens in various electoral area which will be helpful during elections and can have latest updates too.',
                         'quality': 3,
                         'thumb_url': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/photos.angel.co/startups/i/267120-9513670dbfe74c170201df0e385d1c2c-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1379663721',
                         'updated_at': '2014-02-06T07:36:36Z'},
            'tags': [{'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/business-development-1',
                       'display_name': 'Business Development',
                       'id': 15525,
                       'name': 'business development',
                       'tag_type': 'SkillTag'},
                      {'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/sales-strategy-and-management',
                       'display_name': 'Sales Strategy and Management',
                       'id': 16928,
                       'name': 'sales strategy and management',
                       'tag_type': 'SkillTag'},
                      {'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/sales-and-marketing-2',
                       'display_name': 'Sales and Marketing',
                       'id': 23989,
                       'name': 'sales and marketing',
                       'tag_type': 'SkillTag'},
                      {'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/australia',
                       'display_name': 'Australia',
                       'id': 1618,
                       'name': 'australia',
                       'tag_type': 'LocationTag'},
                      {'angellist_url': 'https://angel.co/sales-2',
                       'display_name': 'Sales',
                       'id': 80488,
                       'name': 'sales',
                       'tag_type': 'RoleTag'}],
            'title': 'Sales Intern',
            'updated_at': '2014-02-06T08:07:57Z'},
           # many more entries elided
           ],
 'last_page': 184,
 'page': 1,
 'per_page': 50,
 'total': 9195}
```

The list you are looking for then is `result['jobs']`, but you'll also have to request additional pages to get all 9195 results.

Comment: I did but it didn't work:
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: @user3278658: right, you need to decode the result to a Unicode value first. In this case the response used UTF-8.

Comment: Does Requests package help in web scraping for HTML pages?
What should I do if I wanna do some thing like this:
requests.get(URL).HTMLparser

Comment: @Rose: No, `requests` only helps sending and receiving data over HTTP. Use something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse the HTML. You could try out [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/), which combines these two tools into one library.

Comment: Thanks my dear brother :)
let me try for it!

Comment: I see I've helped you on this and another question of yours. I would *really* appreciate it if you could mark answers you found helpful as such. We both get points if you do! :-)

Comment: brother I'm using MySQLdb package. following command shows result in shell/terminal but when I check mysql workbench db, no result is inserted there :(
query is:
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO WebScraping(Title,Description) VALUES ('Pepsi','a bottle')")

Comment: Do remember to `connection.commit()` your transaction. That's an entirely separate issue though.

Comment: should I use this command after insert query or before that...?
it gives error:
NameError: name 'connection' is not defined

Comment: @Rose: I used a generic name; you *do* have to think a little yourself. I cannot see your code, so I used the name `connection`. What is the database connection called in your code? Use that name. You commit a transaction when you are done sending with your inserts and want the changes to be visible to other connections.